# A Script to Find Average Colors of all Layers/Images in Photoshop and Save with Filename of Average Color

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a folder of 300+ profile skintones that I must sort by color from light tones to dark tone. I can create an action to get the average colors for each of the skintones, but I won't be able to rename the file automatically to match each color to identifies with.

Is it possible to create a script that will find the average color (of the whole photo; I usually just Filter>Blur>Average the layer) for each image in the folder and then save the new image with the RGB or Hex name of the average color added before the original file name?

EX: After the script Filter>Blur>Average the layer. The average color for skintone01.jpg is #ad8475 so it will rename the file to ad8475-skintone01.jpg

Also, I'm not sure if this is possible, but is there a way to arrange all the layers in accordance to its average color using script. I don't think it could but figure since we're on that topic, might as well get it out there.

EDIT: I just tested a few of the photos and found that sorting by HEX is not ideal as Windows sort the hex code in a weird order. So far, I found that sorting it by RGB number is ideal as long as there is spaces between all three numbers.

EX: If average color RGB is 110 73 58, then the script will name the new file "110 73 58 skintone01.jpg" and not "1107358 skintone01.jpg". Again, this is due to how Windows sort the files.

**Bascially, this is what I want to do with the script for each photos in the folder:

1. Duplicate Layer
2. Filter > Blur > Average
3. Copy RGB Values of current layer
4. Turn current layer (one with the average color) invisible
5. Save image with RGB values before the original filename (with a space between each RBG value).**

Comment: This is an interesting question. And I think I know where you are going with this. To clarify, not knowing what your source images actually look like: Do you have an example of the skin stone image before and after the average blur? Are you currently manually selecting whereabouts on the image you make the RGB values from? The script should be straight forward apart from Stage 3, which is the tricky part.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this. The following are examples image of a skintone [link](https://imagez.to/i/B6vBxm5x.png) and its average [link](https://imagez.to/i/5CzOW8g9.jpg) using blur>average of the whole image. Because I'm averaging the duplicated layer of the whole image, it didn't matter where I made the RGB value from. Yes, part 3 and on is the tricky part as it is not possible to do with just PSP actions but I'm unfamiliar with scripting as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you so much, Ghoul Fool!

I played around with your script along with some research and managed to fix the error Photoshop thew at me. I also made some tweaks to my liking. This is the resulting codes I'm using:

```
// Set reference for active document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

// get filename
myFileName = srcDoc.name;
//docName = myFileName.substring(0,myFileName.lastIndexOf("."));  

//Duplicate Layer and call it "blurred"
var layerName = "blurred";
srcDoc.activeLayer.duplicate().name = layerName;

//Select "Blurred" Layer
activeDocument.activeLayer = activeDocument.artLayers.getByName("blurred");  

// Filter > Blur > Average
srcDoc.activeLayer.applyAverage();

// remove any sample first
srcDoc.colorSamplers.removeAll();

// get width and height of image
var w = srcDoc.width.value;
var h = srcDoc.height.value;

// get positions of the center of the image 
//var x = 0;
//var y = 0;
var x = Math.round(w/2);
var y = Math.round(h/2);

// will pick a sample from the middle of the image
var px = [UnitValue(x) , UnitValue(y)]; 
var skinSampler = srcDoc.colorSamplers.add(px);

// Copy RGB Values of current layer  with 3 decimal spaces
var myColor = skinSampler.color; 
var rgb_R = Math.round(myColor.rgb.red*1000)/1000; 
var rgb_G = Math.round(myColor.rgb.green*1000)/1000; 
var rgb_B = Math.round(myColor.rgb.blue*1000)/1000; 

// remove that sample no we know it's value
srcDoc.colorSamplers.removeAll();

// Turn current layer (one with the average color) invisible
srcDoc.activeLayer.visible = false;

// Save image with RGB values before the original filename (with a space between each RBG value).
mySaveName = rgb_R + " " + rgb_G +  " " + rgb_B +  " "  + myFileName;

// Set filePath and fileName to source path
var filePath = srcDoc.path + "/"  + mySaveName;

// save as jpeg
jpegIt(filePath, 12);

// function for saving as jpeg
function jpegIt(filePath, myJpgQuality)
{
  if(! myJpgQuality) myJpgQuality = 12;

  // Flatten the jpg
  activeDocument.flatten();

  // jpg file options
  var jpgFile = new File(filePath);
  jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
  jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.OPTIMIZEDBASELINE;
  jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
  jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
  jpgSaveOptions.quality = myJpgQuality;

  activeDocument.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);

  //close without saving
  app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}
```

All I did was make the "blurred" layer active before averaging it, then change the coding for Copying RGB Value to fit the values from sampling code. Then I added the codes so that it will round the result up to 3 decimal points.

After I tried to see if I can get the script to save all new image to a new folder, but couldn't figured out how. LOL. But at least I got it working.

Thank you so much for your help. I wouldn't be able to to this without you and would probably be sitting in front of my computer for hours. :D

Comment: I know this party's long over, but for any future wanderers having the same RGB sorting dilemma you had: convert your RGB to HSL, and use the 0-padded [H]ue value for sorting. Hues traverse the spectrum from 0-360, so color ordering will just work. [S]aturation (0=less color, 1=more color) and [L]ightness (0=black, 1=white) give you an added bonus of strict/weak ordering out of the box. Or rearrange the three of them for a different sort strategy. Regardless, it will always sort sanely (unlike RGB). Just be sure to cast the floats to ints or replace the decimal before using in filename, obv.

Answer (score 2):

Okay here's the what you need:

```
// Set reference for active document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

// get filename
myFileName = srcDoc.name;
//docName = myFileName.substring(0,myFileName.lastIndexOf("."));  

//Duplicate Layer and call it "blurred"
var layerName = "blurred";
srcDoc.activeLayer.duplicate().name = layerName;

// Filter > Blur > Average
srcDoc.activeLayer.applyAverage();


// remove any sample first
srcDoc.colorSamplers.removeAll();

// get width and height of image
var w = srcDoc.width.value;
var h = srcDoc.height.value;

// get positions of the center of the image 
//var x = 0;
//var y = 0;
var x = Math.round(w/2);
var y = Math.round(h/2);

// will pick a sample from the middle of the image
var px = [UnitValue(x) , UnitValue(y)]; 
var skinSampler = srcDoc.colorSamplers.add(px);

// Copy RGB Values of current layer
var myColour = myColorSampler.color; 
var rgb_R = myColor.rgb.red; 
var rgb_G = myColor.rgb.green; 
var rgb_B = myColor.rgb.blue; 

// remove that sample no we know it's value
srcDoc.colorSamplers.removeAll();

// Turn current layer (one with the average color) invisible
srcDoc.activeLayer.visible = false;

// Save image with RGB values before the original filename (with a space between each RBG value).
mySaveName = rgb_R + " " + rgb_G + rgb_B + myFileName;

// Set filePath and fileName to source path
var filePath = srcDoc.path + "/"  + mySaveName;

// save as jpeg
jpegIt(filePath, 12);

// function for saving as jpeg
function jpegIt(filePath, myJpgQuality)
{
  if(! myJpgQuality) myJpgQuality = 12;

  // Flatten the jpg
  activeDocument.flatten();

  // jpg file options
  var jpgFile = new File(filePath);
  jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
  jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.OPTIMIZEDBASELINE;
  jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
  jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
  jpgSaveOptions.quality = myJpgQuality;

  activeDocument.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);

  //close without saving
  app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}
```

I'm doing this blind, should work though.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I've just finished testing it and Adobe is throwing back an error that "srcDoc.activeLayer.applyAvergeBlur(avg);" is not a function.

Comment: I've changed it to applyAverage(); instead. Give it a go now

Comment: The fix works, but now it's throwing back this error: [link](https://imagez.to/i/pT8J29gF.jpg). I think it might have to do something with  the fact that it's blurring the bottom layer instead of the duplicated one.

Comment: After playing around for a bit, I added a bit of code after the duplicate layer part so the script would select the "blurred" layer `activeDocument.activeLayer = activeDocument.artLayers.getByName("blurred");`